# numberOfSectionsInTableView for two UITableViews

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have two `UITableView` which appears according to `UISegmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex`. The first table is **grouped** style and the second is **plain**.

NSFetchedResultsController is for the first UITableView, and NSMutableArray for the second.

In my **numberOfSectionsInTableView**:

```
return [_fetchedResultsController.sections count];
```

In this case the second UITableView's data displays for 3 times (because FirstTableView section count = 3).

I would like for the second tableView **numberOfSectionsInTableView**

`return 1;`

Comment: plz explain u r question some more clearly.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check which tableview you are displaying before returning the count. You can use the `tableView` input param for this.

For eg:-

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    if (tableView == self.firstTableView) //or (tableView == firstTableView)
       return [_fetchedResultsController.sections count];
    else 
       return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following condition...

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{

    if(tableView == firstTableView)
         return 1;
    else if (tableView == secondTableView)
         return 2;
    //... and so on you can do like this....
}
```

All the best !!!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are setting the same data source for both table views. If that is the case, then in your:

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
   if(tableView == firstTableView){ //assuming you have a reference to the first table view
         return [_fetchedResultsController.sections count];
   }else{
         return 1;
   }
}
```

You will have to do this in all your datasource methods. Instead it would be easier to make the datasource of the tableviews different.
To do this you can drag an object (the blue cube ) from the object library and set its class as say, `SecondTableDatasource`. And then set this object as the datasource for your second table, and implement the corresponding datasource methods in that class.

Answer (score 0):

You can add tag for each tableView and check for each tag in `numberOfSectionsInTableView`